# Python: Generating HTML output documentation based on Docstring

Tags: python, documentation, docstring

Is there a way to easily output html documentation based on python docstrings?

If there are, how to do this? I am familiar with HTML/CSS so theming the output is not important, but if there are existing themes, they would help.

I am hoping for a process that can be repeated everytime the code is updated.

Comment: Why is this question (and its answers) downvoted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Epydoc](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/manual-docstring.html) that seems to do what you need

Comment: Thanks a lot! What I did (virtualenv was) pip install epydoc & generated html output like this: "epydoc --html app.py -o app" (html putput for app.py to a folder called 'app')

Comment: with --css parameter you can select the styling from "blue, default, grayscale, black, green, white"

Answer (score 0):

[Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/) is another tool that can be used to create documentation for python, it also supports C and C++.